# Android Bluetooth connect()

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

Моя попытка написания приложения для телефона с `bluetooth`. Помогите, пожалуйста, решить проблему с `bluetoothsocket.connect()`.

MainActivity.java

```java
package abu.bluetooth_light;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothServerSocket;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;

    ListView listview;
    TextView light;
    Button btnnew;

    BluetoothAdapter bluetoothadapter;

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    ArrayList<String> arraylist;

    UUID myUUID;

    ThreadConnectBTdevice myThreadConnectBTdevice;
    ThreadConnected myThreadConnected;

    FrameLayout butpanel;

    private StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final String UUID_STRING_WELL_KNOWN_SPP = "454D5500-454D-2D57-4552-42554E474B42";
                                                 //454D5501-454D-2D57-4552-42554E474B42

        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

        light = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.light);

        butpanel = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.butpanel);

        myUUID = UUID.fromString(UUID_STRING_WELL_KNOWN_SPP);
        bluetoothadapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        if (!bluetoothadapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        }
    }

    private void setup() { // Создание списка сопряжённых Bluetooth-устройств
        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = bluetoothadapter.getBondedDevices();
        if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
            arraylist = new ArrayList<>();
            for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
                arraylist.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
            }

            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arraylist);
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);

            listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    listview.setVisibility(View.GONE); // После клика скрываем список

                    String itemValue = (String) listview.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    String MAC = itemValue.substring(itemValue.length() - 17);

                    BluetoothDevice device2 = bluetoothadapter.getRemoteDevice(MAC);

                    myThreadConnectBTdevice = new ThreadConnectBTdevice(device2);
                    myThreadConnectBTdevice.start();
                }
            });

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (myThreadConnectBTdevice != null) myThreadConnectBTdevice.cancel();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                setup();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth не включен", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    }

    private class ThreadConnectBTdevice extends Thread { // поток для коннекта с bluetooth
        private BluetoothSocket bluetoothsocket = null;
        private BluetoothDevice device;

        public ThreadConnectBTdevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
            try {
                bluetoothsocket = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(myUUID);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    public void run() { //коннект
        bluetoothadapter.cancelDiscovery();
        boolean success = false;
        try {
            bluetoothsocket.connect();
            success = true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Нет коннекта, проверьте Bluetooth-устройство", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    listview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });

            try {
                bluetoothsocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if (success) { // если законектились, открываем панель с кнопками и запускаем поток приема и отправки данных
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    butpanel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //открываем панель с кнопками
                }
            });
            myThreadConnected = new ThreadConnected(bluetoothsocket);
            myThreadConnected.start(); //запускаем поток приема и отправки данных
        }
    }

    public void cancel() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Close - BluetoothSocket", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        try {
            bluetoothsocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

    private class ThreadConnected extends Thread{ // Поток - прием и отправка данных

        private final InputStream connectedInputStream;
        private final OutputStream connectedOutputStream;

        private String sbprint;

        public ThreadConnected(BluetoothSocket socket){
            InputStream in = null;
            OutputStream out = null;

            try {
                in = socket.getInputStream();
                out = socket.getOutputStream();
            }
            catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            connectedInputStream = in;
            connectedOutputStream = out;
        }

        @Override
        public void run(){ // Прием данных
            while (true){
                try {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1];
                    int bytes = connectedInputStream.read(buffer);
                    String strIncom = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
                    sb.append(strIncom); //собираем символы в строку
                    int endOfLineIndex = sb.indexOf("\r\n"); //определяем конец строки

                    if (endOfLineIndex > 0) {
                        sbprint = sb.substring(0, endOfLineIndex);
                        sb.delete(0, sb.length());

                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                switch (sbprint) {
                                    case "Light on":
                                        light.setText(sbprint);
                                        break;
                                    case "Light off":
                                        light.setText(sbprint);
                                        break;
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException e){
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        public void write(byte[] buffer){
            try{
                connectedOutputStream.write(buffer);
            }
            catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void onClickbtn1(View v){
        if (myThreadConnected != null){
            byte[] bytesToSend = "a".getBytes();
            myThreadConnected.write(bytesToSend);
        }
    }

    public void onClickbtn2(View v){
        if (myThreadConnected != null){
            byte[] bytesToSend = "A".getBytes();
            myThreadConnected.write(bytesToSend);
        }
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```xml
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="202dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </ListView>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#e7e7e5"
        android:id="@+id/butpanel"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:text="On"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:onClick="onClickbtn1"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/light"
            android:text="Light"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:text="Off"
            android:layout_gravity="right|top"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:onClick="onClickbtn2"/>

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: мне почему-то кажется что вы работаете с микроконтроллером, но только в чем собственно проблема?

Comment: Какую проблему предлагается решить?

Comment: @Эникейщик, меня этот вопрос сейчас очень сильно тоже интересует, потому-что я диплом пишу с очень похожим кодом)) поэтому чисто гипотетически я мог решать уже подобную проблему))

Comment: при попытке подключиться к устройству не проходит  connect()